# How can I get this to restart if it isn't an english result?

Tags: node.js, express

I have an API at https://dev-qaboomapi.azurewebsites.net/randmovie. I have a txt file that lists all movie IDs from https://themoviedb.org and one is selected at random and the information is presented at the API address above. What I can't work out is how to get it to check if the result is an english language movie and then try again if it isn't.

I have an If Else statement that checks the result is an english language movie but I can't work out if it isn't how to start the process again.

```
var appRouter = function (app) {
    app.get("/randMovie", function (req, res) {
        const fetchURL = require('fetch').fetchUrl;
        const fs = require('fs');

        const data = fs.readFileSync('./db/MovieIDs.txt') + '';
        const splitData = data.split('\n');
        const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * splitData.length);
        const line = splitData.splice(randomNumber, 1);
        const lineDATA = line.toString()

        const api = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        var movieID = lineDATA
        var URL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + movieID + '?api_key=' + api + "&append_to_response=videos"

        fetchURL(URL, function(error, meta, body){
            var movieString = body.toString()
            var movieJSON = JSON.parse(movieString)

            if(movieJSON.original_language == "en") {
                res.status(200).send(movieJSON);
            } else {
                // Not sure what to put here
            }
        })
    });
}
module.exports = appRouter;
```

I would like it to only return the details of the movie when it is:

```
if(movieJSON.original_language == "en")
```

and retry when it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can try, but make sure that function does not run infinity if result is not in English.

```
var appRouter = function (app) {
app.get("/randMovie", function (req, res) {
   retrieveData(req, res);
}
```

Definition of `retrieveData`

```
retrieveData(req, res){
        const fetchURL = require('fetch').fetchUrl;
        const fs = require('fs');

        const data = fs.readFileSync('./db/MovieIDs.txt') + '';
        const splitData = data.split('\n');
        const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * splitData.length);
        const line = splitData.splice(randomNumber, 1);
        const lineDATA = line.toString()

        const api = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
        var movieID = lineDATA
        var URL = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' + movieID + '?api_key=' + api + "&append_to_response=videos"

        fetchURL(URL, function(error, meta, body){
            var movieString = body.toString()
            var movieJSON = JSON.parse(movieString)

            if(movieJSON.original_language == "en") {
                res.status(200).send(movieJSON);
            } else {
                // Not sure what to put here
                retrieveData(req, res);
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: OK thanks a lot. I will give it a go tomorrow and let you know how I go.